# Delayed program flow acting spotty

Tags: python, python-2.7, vlc

I am fairly new at writing python so forgive me if I seem like I don't know what i'm doing. The goal I am trying to achieve is an automated video player (this is for my company). At 9:30 AM, the task scheduler will start this python file. This is what the code at 9:30 looks like:

```
This script runs all day and plays a commercial using VLC media player every 30 minutes
# Notes:
# Python uses a 24 hour format, so 2:30 PM = 14:30
# All spaces in video files names must be replaced by an underscore i.e. no spaces in the file name
#   ...or this will not work
#   Example: "Example Video Name.wmv" would need to be changed to "Example_Video_Name.wmv"

import time
import os
import subprocess
import datetime

# start here at 9:30AM, windows task scheduler takes care of this
print "It is 9:30, playing first video"
# set our working directory
os.chdir("C:\Commercials")
# the commercial to be played is specified here
commName = "Robotow_Heavy_Duty.wmv"
# get the length in seconds of the commercial
commLength = subprocess.check_output('ffprobe -i ' + commName + ' -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"')
# start the file
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\\vlc.exe', '-f', 'C:\Commercials\\' + commName])
# delay closing the file until it is finished playing
time.sleep(float(commLength))
# kill the VLC player
p.terminate()

print "finished playing " + commName
```

What happens is pretty well commented, the video runs, then gets killed after it's duration has passed. After that, the following code makes it sleep until 10:

```
print "finished playing " + commName
# delay workflow until 10:00 AM
print "Waiting until 10:00 to run next commercial..."
for i in xrange(0, 365):
    # sleep until 10:00 AM
    t = datetime.datetime.today()
    future = datetime.datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day, 10, 00)
    if t.hour >= 10 and t.minute >= 00:
        future += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    time.sleep((future-t).seconds)
```

Then the code from the beginning is repeated with a different video name and it sleeps until 10:30. What is weird about this, is it will work about 75% of the time. It will go by itself and be all good until about 11:00 (it wont play the 11:00 video) and other times it will go until 1:30, etc. The structure I am using for time should check out. For example, this is what I would do to make it sleep until 3:00 PM:

```
for i in xrange(0, 365):
# sleep until 3:00 PM
t = datetime.datetime.today()
future = datetime.datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day, 15, 00)
if t.hour >= 15 and t.minute >= 00:
    future += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
time.sleep((future-t).seconds)
```

I know this is a lot, I apologize for that. If you have any input on how I can do this better or why this is acting up, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: What is handling the code rerunning every 30 minutes? It seems like you use windows task scheduler to run the code once, then you use python to run the a different video every 30 minutes based on the time. Is that correct?

Comment: @AustinA that is correct. That last "for" in my initial post sleeps it until whichever time I select, then after that criteria has been met, the next commerical plays and so on.

Comment: So, I don't think that is the best way to go about designing this workflow. Have you thought about using the task scheduler to execute the code every 30 minutes instead? You would have to do write some logic to figure out what video to play based on the time. But the advantage in this is you don't have a single script that you're trying to run for hours and hours. Instead, the task scheduler runs the script, the video plays, then script dies until the scheduler runs the code again. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AustinA =That makes alot of sense. That is exactly how we do it now. The reason we want to switch it to one big file, is that these videos often rotate and every time we switch a commerical, we need to go into a million different files and change the name, the duration, etc. My boss would prefer if we used one file per day that gets launched once. It is much easier to change around files as much as we do.

Comment: That helps me understand the motivation to moving to a single file. Let's take a few steps back to help further my understanding. It sounds like you have a TV setup in a lobby/public space that plays product commercials every 30 minutes or so. Are all of these commercials stored locally at `C:\Commercials\\`? It also sounds like the commercials that you want to play on a given day are always different? How do you decide what commercials are going to be played that day?

Comment: @AustinA you are correct (I swear you're a mind reader). We only play 20 videos a day so I just manually shuffle the order in which they play myself. They are all in that one folder as well. The commercials that play on monday are the same as all of the other days, the order is just different. Does that help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134529/discussion-between-austin-a-and-mattp341).